# Dynamic SQL with loop through table rows with cursor in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, dynamic-sql, database-cursor

I have two tables (`#aaa_Test` & `#bbb_Test`). I want to loop through each row of the `#aaa_Test` table.

I need to iterate every row of `#aaa_Test` using a cursor. Also, I have a dynamic SQL statement I've created in a stored procedure. I want to use dynamic SQL and cursor both together to generate my final query.
I'm having a hard time figuring out the right way to approach this problem.

Here's what I have done.

These are my two tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #aaa_Test;

CREATE TABLE #aaa_Test 
(
    [Columnname] VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    [Length] VARCHAR (500) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #aaa_Test
VALUES ('Hole', '18'), ('Project', '8'), ('Source', '10');

SELECT * FROM #aaa_Test;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #bbb_Test;

CREATE TABLE #bbb_Test 
(
    [Hole] VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    [Project] VARCHAR (500) NOT NULL,
    [source] VARCHAR (500) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #bbb_Test
VALUES ('08SWRB001', 'WDW', 'Droll'),
       ('08SWRB002', 'WDWWDW', 'Gup'),
       ('08SWRB003', 'WDWMD', 'Sh');

SELECT * FROM #bbb_Test;
```

This is my final select query that I want in output(Desired Result) but I wanted dynamic as I have more than 1000 entries of column name for `#aaa*Test.*` If you look at the below query closely, Hole, Project and source come from column name of #aaa_test table. I want this column name dynamic rather than hard coding each column name as I have so many entries of column name in #aaa*Test table* .

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(Hole, SPACE((SELECT [Length] FROM #aaa_Test 
                        WHERE columnname = 'Hole') - LEN(Hole))) AS Hole,
    CONCAT(Project, SPACE((SELECT [Length] FROM #aaa_Test 
                           WHERE columnname='Project') - LEN(project))) AS project,
    CONCAT([Source], SPACE((SELECT [Length] FROM #aaa_Test 
                            WHERE columnname='Source') - LEN([source]))) AS [source]
FROM 
    #bbb_Test;
```

This is the combination of my dynamic SQL and cursor:

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @MyField YourFieldDataType;

BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
        SELECT * FROM #aaa_Test as a;     

    OPEN @MyCursor; 

    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @MyField;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);

        SET @SQL = '';

        SELECT @SQL = @SQL + ' SELECT Concat(' + QUOTENAME(a.[Columnname], '') + ',SPACE((SELECT [Length] from #aaa_Test where columnname = '+ QUOTENAME(a.[columnname], '''') +'-LEN(' + QUOTENAME(a.[Columnname],'') +' as '+ QUOTENAME(a.[Columnname],'')    
        FROM #bbb_Test AS b;

        PRINT @SQL; 
  
        FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @MyField; 
    END; 

    EXEC(@SQL);

    CLOSE @MyCursor;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;
```

Comment: I am using SQL version -18.11.1

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake. I have changed the dummy example. Now, space always has a positive value.

Comment: This i the version Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Feb 23 2022 11:32:53   Copyright (C) 2021 Microsoft Corporation

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a cursor for this and, since you're building the query from `#aaa_Test` anyway, you don't need to pull the length from the #temp table as a subquery in every row, either:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT ';

SELECT @sql += STRING_AGG(CONVERT
(
  nvarchar(max), 
  CONCAT
  (
    char(13), char(10),
    'CONCAT(',
    QUOTENAME(Columnname), 
    ',SPACE(',
    CONVERT(varchar(11), [Length]),
    '-LEN(', 
    QUOTENAME(Columnname), 
    '))) AS ',
    QUOTENAME(Columnname)
  )
), ',')
FROM #aaa_Test;

SET @sql += char(13) + char(10) + N' FROM #bbb_Test;';


SELECT @sql;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Output:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT([Hole],SPACE(18-LEN([Hole]))) AS [Hole],
CONCAT([Project],SPACE(8-LEN([Project]))) AS [Project],
CONCAT([Source],SPACE(10-LEN([Source]))) AS [Source]
FROM #bbb_Test;
```

| Hole | Project | Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08SWRB001 | WDW | Droll |
| 08SWRB002 | WDWWDW | Gup |
| 08SWRB003 | WDWMD | Sh |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f7c7e054c94b2cf0aa126490c56c92f1)